# Where should I deploy my application?

Tags: vps, deployment

I have VPS and I don`t know the best way.
/var/www/my_app or /home/user/www/my_app or something else? Which alternate is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you app wherever you want. That being said if you chose `/var/www...` then you will be using a path that is fairly common. One of the benefits of this is that many tutorials and other documentation commonly use /var/www so it's easy to follow them and relate to your own website/app.

Comment: maybe create special user "deploy" and put /home/deploy/www?